# How do I set height of the container to wrap content of gridview/layout grid

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, containers

So I am trying to create an app for my grocery store. It has a home screen where it shows a grid of few products

like this

[image]

and code for home screen is as follows:

```
    CustomScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        slivers: [
              // App Bar
              SliverAppBar(..),
              // Search Button
              !_showMobileModule ? SliverPersistentHeader(..) : SliverToBoxAdapter(),
              SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Center(
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: Dimensions.WEB_MAX_WIDTH,
                      child: !_showMobileModule ? Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,              children: [
                      
                            BannerView(isFeatured: false),
                            CategoryView(),
                            //PopularStoreView(isPopular: true, isFeatured: false),
                            ItemCampaignView(),
                            PopularItemView(isPopular: true),
                            //ItemCampaignView(),
                            //PopularStoreView(isPopular: false, isFeatured: false),
                            PopularItemView(isPopular: false),
                            
                        ]) : ModuleView(splashController: splashController),
                      )),
                  ),
        ],
    ),
```

and the code for popular item grid is:

```
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return GetBuilder<ItemController>(builder: (itemController) {
        List<Item> _itemList = isPopular
            ? itemController.popularItemList
            : itemController.reviewedItemList;
    
        return (_itemList != null && _itemList.length == 0)
            ? SizedBox()
            : Column(
          children: [
            Padding(..), // Popular item text
            Container(
              height: 600,
              child:
              _itemList != null
                  ? LayoutGrid(
                columnSizes: [1.fr, 1.fr],
                rowSizes: const [auto, auto, auto, auto],
                rowGap: 15,
                columnGap: 1,
                children: [
                  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    Padding(..), //code for item card
                ],
              ) : PopularItemShimmer(enabled: _itemList == null),
            ),
    
          ],
        );
    
      });
```

When I run this app on other devices it shows bounding error like this:

[image]

for now I've hard coded height for the container in popular item grid.

Is there a way I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your content within the `SliverToBoxAdapter` is too long and it compressed to the size of the `Size` provided, you may try replace `SliverToBoxAdapter` with `SliverFillRemaining` and see whether the bounding still persist.